# Why is Dolores Umbridge the Headmistress of Hogwarts in the Cursed Child?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, Umbridge becomes Headmistress of Hogwarts after Dumbledore's sacking, but Dumbledore gets reinstated at the end.

But however, in *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, in the alternate reality where Cedric Diggory becomes a Death Eater, Umbridge is still Headmistress.

So what happened in this timeline's version of Order of the Phoenix? Did Dumbledore still get reinstated, then Snape, then Umbridge? After all, Scorpius said that Snape killed Dumbledore and if someone else did that, Snape made no attempt to correct him. Or did Dumbledore get reinstated, then Umbridge got reinstated after Dumbledore died?

Comment: Could you put some more effort into your titles in the future, a lot of your posts seem to be of the form `keyword1 - keyword2 - keyword3 etc.` A good title should describe the main question you are asking whilst being brief.

Comment: It isn't such a stretch to believe - remember, her being Headmistress in Cursed Child is 19+ years after the events of book 5. And - she was already fully culpable w/ a dictatorial regime in the 'real' timeline by Book 7 and held a high position in the Ministry then. It stands to reason that she would be promoted

Comment: @NKCampbell In the real timeline, though, she is sent to Azkaban for life after _Deathly Hallows_. Besides, would headmistress of a secondary school really be a promotion from her ministry position as Head of the Anti-Muggle Evilness Office?

Comment: Because HPATCC is rubbish.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill, please.  That is insulting to perfectly good rubbish, which generally served a purpose before being used and thrown away. Cursed Child aspires to be rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

The order of succession is: Dumbledore, then Umbridge (during OotP) then Dumbledore again. After Dumbledore is killed (in HBP) Snape gets the job.  At *some point* after Harry's death (in CC's alternate timeline) Voldemort reinstates Umbridge, and Snape returns to his old job.

Umbridge is made Headmistress after Snape, probably because she was a better candidate for the job. Umbridge had proven willing to gloss over both the Ministry's failings and the activities of Voldemort, who preferred secrecy. Umbridge is better able to uphold an image of normalcy as she had no prior association with Death Eaters, unlike Snape, who killed the previous headmaster.

Answer (score -1):

Hm, probably Snape never became headmaster? Maybe Umbridge became headmaster after the battle because she is pureblood supremacist and therefore ok to Voldemort.

Comment: Got any evidence for this that you could [edit] in to back your answer up? Or is it only pure speculation?

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum, it's a question-and-answer site. Your post needs to actually attempt to answer the question - you've asked another question, and started a statement with "maybe". Neither provide an answer.